# Double "for" Loop in R, with 2nd "for" Loop using the argument of 1st "for" Loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a function in R involving double "for" loop, with 2nd "for" Loop using the argument of 1st "for" Loop. However, R seems to "forgot" about variables defined in the 1st loop (such as "temp" and "i") when it goes to the 2nd loop.

This is my code (errors line are marked with ###):

```
pop.1996.mod <- data.frame(NULL)
number.of.expanded.rows <- 18
timeVec <- system.time(
    for (i in 1:5){
        cat("Working on row ",i," out of ",nrow(pop.1996.clean),".\n",sep="")
        temp <- data.frame(matrix(0,number.of.expanded.rows,5))
        temp[1] <- pop.1996.clean[i,1]
        temp[2] <- pop.1996.clean[i,2]
        #seifa code
        position <- binarySearch(pop.1996.clean[i,1],postcodedata.1996.clean$pcode)
        temp[5] <- postcodedata.1996.clean$seifa[position]
            for (j in 3:(ncol(pop.1996.clean))
                temp[j-2,3] <- pop.1996.clean[i,j]
            ### Error: unexpected symbol in:
            ### "for (j in 3:(ncol(pop.1996.clean))
            ### temp"
                temp[j-2,4] <- sum(ihd.1996.clean$pcode==pop.1996.clean[i,1] && ihd.1996.clean$sex==pop.1996.clean[i,2] && ihd.1996.clean[,j]==1)
            ### Error in `[.data.frame`(pop.1996.clean, i, 1) : object 'i' not found
                pop.1996.mod <- rbind(pop.1996.mod,temp)
            ### Error in rbind(pop.1996.mod, temp) : object 'temp' not found
        }
    )
cat("\n The time taken is", round(timeVec[3]), "seconds.\n\n")
```

Thank you.

Comment: In your second for loop a `)`, a `{` and a `}` is missing.

Comment: Sometimes error messages are a bit unclear.  "Unexpected symbol" means some item like "("  or "{" shows up where it shouldn't.  99% of the time it's because you forgot to close a previous bracket.   Because of that error,  the subsequent code is mis-parsed, leading to the remaining error messages you received.